# OpenVPN through Tunnelblick - "Unrouteable TLS received" connecting to Riseup VPN

Tags: mac, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to RiseupVPN on my Macbook Pro M2 running macOS 14.1 Sonoma. I downloaded the branded BitmaskVPN client from them, and with 2 nondescript errors in the installation, I launched it, and saw it fail to connect as I tried dozens of times. Luckily, RiseUp has a tutorial on how to access the VPN with Tunnelblick.

[Ordinary macOS download page](https://riseup.net/en/vpn/macos)
["OpenVPN for Mac" tutorial](https://we.riseup.net/riseuphelp+en/openvpn-mac)

I configured Tunnelblick exactly as the tutorial would have me, just substituting my name and preferred VPN gateway. `/Users/rocky/Library/RiseupCA.pem` was where I put their certificate, and the file `/Users/rocky/Library/Application\ Support/riseup.ovpn` is the following:

```
client
dev tun
auth-user-pass
remote vpn15-sea.riseup.net 1194
remote-cert-tls server
ca /Users/rocky/Library/RiseupCA.pem
```

I get these repetitive error messages about a TLS failure.

```
2023-11-24 20:26:39.659916 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET]<IP_ADDRESS>:1194 (si=3 op=P_ACK_V1)
2023-11-24 20:26:41.961382 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET]<IP_ADDRESS>:1194 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
2023-11-24 20:26:41.961567 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET]<IP_ADDRESS>.55:1194 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
2023-11-24 20:26:45.382749 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET]<IP_ADDRESS>.55:1194 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
2023-11-24 20:26:45.382938 TLS Error: Unroutable control packet received from [AF_INET]<IP_ADDRESS>:1194 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
```

How can I resolve these issues so that I can use the VPN?

### External links

[sizeofcat's blog post on this process](https://sizeof.cat/post/riseup-riseupvpn-to-openvpn/)
[A very similar issue to mine from 10 months ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1763535/openvpn-tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-macos)